# Differences of 伴う and 同伴する

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances, wago-and-kango

I'm trying to understand the nuanced differences between 伴う and 同伴する.

My research ([Weblio:伴う](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%86), [Weblio:同伴](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%8C%E4%BC%B4)) has led me to believe that:

**同伴{どうはん}する** means "a person accompanies another person", and not much outside that scope.

**伴{ともな}う** is the more general "to accompany, to follow along with" which may be used to talk about anything, such as wind accompanying a storm, or one problem accompanying another.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. Are the above assumptions correct? Are there any other nuances worth pointing out?
2. Does 同伴する refer to one person accompanying another exclusively, or can it be anything that accompanies a person? (ex: An aura of depression follows him wherever he goes.)
3. Is there any case where 伴う can not be used to mean "to accompany"? (Note: I'm asking for patently wrong cases here, not cases where 同伴する or some other word might be better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > *Are the above assumptions correct? Are there any other nuances worth pointing out?*

   Almost correct, but one important thing is that the verbs are two-faceted words.

   - A が B **に**同伴する／伴う → *A accompanies B*
   - A が B **を**同伴する／伴う → *A is accompanied by B*
2. > *Does 同伴する refer to one person accompanying another exclusively, or can it be anything that accompanies a person? (ex: An aura of depression follows him wherever he goes.)*

   Yes, people only, accompany**ing** or accompani**ed** by another. However, compounds such as 同伴者 usually only mean "accompany**ing** person".
3. > *Is there any case where 伴う can not be used to mean "to accompany"? (Note: I'm asking for patently wrong cases here, not cases where 同伴する or some other word might be better.)*

   First, *accompany* in music context ("to perform another part") is another word in Japanese: 伴奏【ばんそう】する (cf. 伴奏 *accompaniment*).

   Second, 伴う is not usable when you put A and B together.

   > *accompanied their advice with a warning* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accompany))
   >   → 警告に助言を**添える**、助言**とともに**警告する (though I think this situation can be handled by a single word, 忠告する)

   The word is also inappropriate when the subject doesn't change or make any move.

   > *the pictures that accompany the text* (again Merriam-Webster)
   >   → 文章に**添えられた**絵／写真、文章に**付随する**絵／写真
   >
   > cf. *the replacement of pictures that accompanies the text revision*
   >   → 本文の改訂に**伴う**絵／写真の差し替え、本文の改訂に**付随する**絵／写真の差し替え